# JSF 2.2 Post Request forward to another view through preRenderView event - PF resources are missing

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Here is the scenario.

View A - Is loaded by typing a URL in the browser. Submit a post request by pressing a primefaces (PF - 5.2)command button and then navigate to another view View B.

View B - Has a  preRenderView event - on postBack=false, which checks for a specific request parameter and if that is present forwards (not redirect) to another view C, using navigation handler.

View C - Problem is when this view loads up, Primefaces object (javascript object) is found as null, e.g. error as

```
 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cw' of null"
```

against this script

```
PrimeFaces.cw("CommandButton","widget_next3",{id:"next3",widgetVar:"widget_next3"});
```

View C has components related to PF, so i guess PF js and css should get added automatically.I didn't added any PF js or css or jquery js manually, all getting included automatically through PF component ResourceDependency. But in this case neither PF css gets included nor js.

-- Everything works fine on View C, if View B - preRenderView event navigates to View C with (redirect) faces-redirect=true.

In an error scenario if i check through jquery - it gives PF object as null.

```
<h:outputScript>
$( document ).ready(function() {
                     console.log( "ready!" );
                     console.log( "Windows PrimeFaces=" + (window.PrimeFaces) );
                     console.log( "PrimeFaces=" + (PrimeFaces) );                        
                }); 
</h:outputScript>
```

But i am wondering why the problem is only with PF (js and css), why JQuery object "$" is working fine - because the above function works fine.

Also in the error scenario if i explicitly include the following then everything is fine

```
<h:outputScript name="primefaces.js" library="primefaces"/>
<h:outputStylesheet name="primefaces.css" library="primefaces" />
<h:outputStylesheet name="theme.css" library="primefaces-aristo" />
```

Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Was this error preceded by the warn "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/"?

I was facing the same error and found out that my browser (chrome) was not loading PrimeFaces scripts after the ajax warning. It's like after the warning, Chrome would set async=true by default and somehow mess up with primefaces javascript files.

In order to test, I added the following instruction in each view and solved the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) { options.async = false; })
});
```

I'm still trying to understand why Chrome is not loading the javascript files through an async request.